# Get height of enter browser window in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to resize a browser (I know... I know...) by the width only, and would like to maintain the users current height of the browser and I'm struggling to get it working correctly under IE8.

if I do:

```
window.resizeTo(document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

Which should in theory, maintain the exact same size, I'm losing roughly 176 pixels from the height... and roughly about the width of the scrollbar.

I can't find any properties which would give me the correct size of the entire browser window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the best solution, but it works.

First, save the current reported height:

```
var oldY = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Second, set the window size to an a known size:

```
window.resizeTo(800, 600);
```

Next determine the amount of padding by subtracting the reported size from the known size:

```
var padX = 800 - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var padY = 600 - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Finally, set the width to the desired value plus `padX`, and the height to the `oldY` plus `padY`.

```
window.resizeTo(desiredWidth + padX, oldY + padY);
```

The downside to this method is that the user may notice the window changing size at the second step of the process.

Comment: I suggest feature detecting `window.outerWidth` before you use this method, that way the double resize is limited to browsers that don't support window.outerWidth/height.