# Obtaining browser scroll height

Tags: java

In a Java Web Application, how can I retrieve the browser scroll height and pass it to jsp backend code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to get the height (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275849/get-height-of-enter-browser-window-in-ie8)) but passing it to the `JSP backend` will require a new request: either by reloading the page and setting the height parameter or via AJAX.